# Matplotlib colorbar - changed behavior for limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I try to limit the range of a colorbar using matplotlib. The old behavior was, that the colorbar could be scaled using `vmin` and `vmax` keywords of the plot function. This affected both the color itself and the labels of the color bar.

Now the behavior seems to be, that only the color is scaled, while the labels remain the automatic ones.

```py
import numpy
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create somehing to plot, maximum value should be much large than 10
z = numpy.random.rand(20, 20) * 57.8412
t = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 20)
x, y = numpy.meshgrid(t, t)

# this is supposed to be the maximum value of the plot
max_value = 25 # or 100

fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

plot = axis.contourf(x, y, z, 100, cmap=None, vmin=0, vmax=max_value)
cbar = plt.colorbar(plot)

plt.show(block=False)
```

The labels of the color bar remain the same for both pictures (up to 58), even though the maximum value should either be 25 for the first picture or 100 for the second one.

How do I restore the hold behavior and also scale the labels of the color bar.

[image: max_value = 100]

[image: max_value = 25]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the desired outcome, but I think you would want to set the levels explicitely.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create somehing to plot, maximum value should be much large than 10
z = np.random.rand(20, 20) * 57.8412
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
x, y = np.meshgrid(t, t)

# this is supposed to be the maximum value of the plot
max_value = 25 # or 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title(f"max_value={max_value}")
cntr = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=np.arange(max_value+1), vmin=0, vmax=max_value)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cntr)

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your values in z are greater than 25. If you want to limit the scale values to 25 or less, you need to either truncate the values in z that are greater than 25, or remove them before you make the plot.

Here is an example of truncating the values in z to 25 or less:

```
import numpy
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

znew = z
znew[z > 25] = 25

t = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 20)
x, y = numpy.meshgrid(t, t)

# this is supposed to be the maximum value of the plot
max_value = 25 # or 100

fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

plot = axis.contourf(x, y, znew, 100, cmap=None, vmin=0, vmax=max_value)
cbar = plt.colorbar(plot)

plt.show(block=False)
```

[image: Contour plot with truncated z values]

Alternatively, you could simply remove those values by setting them to `NaN`:

```
znew = z
znew[z > 25] = numpy.nan

t = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 20)
x, y = numpy.meshgrid(t, t)

# this is supposed to be the maximum value of the plot
max_value = 25 # or 100

fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

plot = axis.contourf(x, y, znew, 100, cmap=None, vmin=0, vmax=max_value)
cbar = plt.colorbar(plot)

plt.show(block=False)
```

[image: Contour plot with z values > 25 removed]

Comment: That does not fix the problem for a maximum value of 100. The labels still only go up to 54. And matplotlib used to limit the values to the set vmax, even if there were larger numbers in the data.